# Power calculation for observational study vs using propensity score matching estimating treatment effect

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, causality, propensity-scores, observational-study

For case-control study study, one can calculate sample size to determine power of the study with respect to particular estimator of interest. Suppose I am interested in treatment effect in case control study with two treatment arms and I have calculated sample size $n=200$ to find effect size $t$ with 0.05 confidence level and 0.9 power. Call this estimator $T_1$.

I could also run propensity score matching to estimate treatment effect. Suppose luckily after matching my sample size reduced to $n_1=180$ and this sample size yields theoretically same effect size $t$ yielding 0.05 confidence and 0.8 power. To make life harder, assume that my calculation is based upon unbalanced design. Then I estimate treatment effect by propensity score matching. Call propensity score estimated treatment effect estimator $T_2$.

Q1: Since power calculation is based on $T_1$, can it be sufficient to deduce $T_2$ having good power?

Q2: The main reason to ask Q1 is that causal inference books(Rubin, Fraser and Rosenbaum) do not have a separate chapter/section on sample size calculation. Theoretically, one probably could do simulation to calculation sample size in this complicated expression but there are too many parameters unknown beforehand. Can conventional calculated sample size be used to power the observational study deploying propensity score methods? In particular, a designed powered for $T_1$ does not seem power for $T_2$ as I do not see formal connection between the two.

Q3: If $T_2$ can be powered by $T_1$'s sample size, can someone provide reference on theoretical proof of this?